# Trac 0.11+ templates location

Tags: trac, templates

I just upgraded to Trac 0.11.4 on Ubuntu and I noticed that the */usr/share/trac/templates* directory no longer exists. As a result, in my trac.ini, the *templates_dir* variable is not set (*[inherit]* section) and where the Trac logo is supposed to be I see the alt text *(please configure the [header_logo] section in trac.ini)*.

Does anyone know where either the templates directory is located or the global trac.ini?

**UPDATE:**
Apperantly the */usr/share/trac/templates* directory only exist if you install Trac from the Ubuntu repositories (*apt-get install trac*). However, when you install Trac manually (when you want the latest version e.g.) this location is not created during installation.

You don't necessarily need a global trac.ini. If the logo is missing from you Trac instance you can easily add it by modifying the *[header_logo]* section of the *conf/trac.ini* of your Trac installation:

```
[header_logo] 
alt = 
height = -1 
link = http://example.org 
src = common/trac_banner.png 
width = -1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not using Trac, but maybe you can find the global trac.ini by using

```
find / -iname "*trac.ini" 2> /dev/null
```

you can replace the first slash ('root') with the folder where trac is residing and you can leave out the '2> /dev/null' if you're comfortable with scrolling through pages of permission denied errors to find the right path. (or if you are searching with the root account)

```
find /usr/bin -iname "*trac.ini"
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Still getting the hang of Unix commands and 'find' wasn't in my arsenal yet. It appears that there is no global trac.ini. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
src = site/your-logo.png
```

Place `your-logo.png` in <trac_environment>/htdocs/

As for the templates, this may help: [TracInterfaceCustomization#ProjectTemplates](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInterfaceCustomization#ProjectTemplates)

Comment: I know that. However, normally when Trac initializes a new environment the default logo is set. In this case it's not. I assume it's set in the global trac.ini if only I could find it.

Comment: The default logo is no longer set in 0.11.  That is to encourage people to set a meaningful logo and hopefully reduce the number of bug reports filed at t.e.o that belong elsewhere.